# Can emacs open a series of files and split windows for each file in a template fashion?

Tags: template

I have a set of ~8 files in a sub-directory structure that is always the same. 
/DirA/File1
/DirA/File2
/DirB/File3
/DirB/File4
...

and I find myself doing these steps to split windows and see/edit all the ~8files:
1 open one of the files in emacs 
2 split windows into around 8 windows with C-x 2 and C-x 3
3 C-x-f to find/load each of the other files
4 change buffer to move the sequence of files from left/right, top/bottom

I was hoping someone might have an idea about how i could use emacs to say load a directory with these files/dirs and do all this splitting of windows and loading of files, assuming the files/sub-directories are always there. Perhaps one needs a certain file present to signify the parent directory eg emacs.template

see example image of tiled frame[image: example]

Comment: Have you looked at https://github.com/bmag/emacs-purpose?  I've not really used it myself (except that spacemacs uses it, I think) -- but I think that's what it's for.

Comment: Reading the question again, perhaps I misunderstood.  You're not opening a fixed number of files always, but rather a variable number of files, just trying to fit as many as possible, or at least some large-ish number, "tiled" into a single emacs frame (emacs "frame" means operating system window)?

Comment: I would open a fixed number of files, about 8, File1 to File8, tiled out with each file displayed in the frame as split windows

Comment: I can't find existing code that does this, I think you'll need a bit of elisp. Maybe this provides inspiration to you/somebody else: https://github.com/lgfang/tiling/blob/master/tiling.el